# I'm trying to create a quiz app. There are some errors in my JS code, I can not click on the buttons or go to the next questions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a quiz app using JS, CSS, and HTML. Most likely, there are some errors in my JS code. I am not able to click on the buttons, go to the next question, or reveal the wrong or right answers colored in green and red. I'm suspecting there is a simple error in one of the functions.

Btw I'm using VS code 1.66.2.

```
//game.js

const question = document.getElementById('question');
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('choice-text')); //array of 4 choices
const progressText = document.getElementById("ProgressText");
const progressBarfull = document.getElementById("progressBarfull");
const questionCounterText = document.getElementById("questionCounter");
const scoreText = document.getElementById("score");
let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = false;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuestions = [];
let questions = [
    {
        question: "Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript?",
        choice1: "<script>",
        choice2: "<javascript>",
        choice3: "<js>",
        choice4: "<Scripting>",
        answer: 1
    },
    {
        question: "What is the correct syntax for referring to an external script called 'xxx.js'?",
        choice1: "<script href='xxx.js'>",
        choice2: "<script name='xxx.js'>",
        choice3: "<script src='xxx.js'>",
        choice4: "<script file='xxx.js'>",
        answer: 3
    },
    {
        question: "How do you write 'Hello World' in an alert box?" ,
        choice1: "msgBox('Hello World');",
        choice2: "alertBox('Hello World');",
        choice3: "msg('Hello World');",
        choice4: "alert('Hello World');",
        answer: 4
    },
];

//constants
const CORRECT_BOUNS=10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS=3;
startGame=function () {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQuestions = [...questions]; //spread operator in js (...) to quickly copy all or part of an array
    getNewQuestion();
};



getNewQuestion = function () {
    if (availableQuestions.length == 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
        localStorage.setItem('mostRecentScore',score);
        //localStorage.setItem("mostRecentScore", score);
        return window.location.assign("/end.html"); //go to the end page
    }
    questionCounter++;
    progressText.innerText = `Question${questionCounter}/${MAX_QUESTIONS}`;
    progressBarfull.style.width = `Question ${(questionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100} ;
    px`;
    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length); //take the integer of the random number
    currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionIndex];
    question.innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;
    choices.forEach(function (choice) {
            const number = choice.dataset["number"];
            choice.innerHTML = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
        });

    availableQuestions.splice(questionIndex, 1); //take the available questions array and get rid of the used ques
    acceptingAnswers = true;
};
choices.forEach(function (choice) {
        choice.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                if (!acceptingAnswers)
                    return;
                acceptingAnswers = false;

                const selectedChoice = e.target;
                const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];
                const classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? "correct" : "incorrect";

                if (classToApply === "correct") { //call incrementScore fun
                    incrementScore(CORRECT_BOUNS);
                } //increment score by correct bonus

                selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
                    getNewQuestion();
                }, 1000);
            });

    });

incrementScore = function (num) {
    score += num;
    scoreText.innerText = score;
};
```

```
//game.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Quick Quiz - Play</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
        <div id="hud">

          <div id="hud-item">

            <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
                Question
            </p>
            <div id="progressBar">
               <div id="progressBarfull">

               </div>
            </div>
          
          </div>
       
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p class="hud-prefix" >
                Score
            </p>
            <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
                0
            </h1>
          </div>

        </div>

        <h2 id="question">What is the answer to this questions?</h2>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>

//game.css
.choice-container{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid rgba(241, 69, 175, 0.25);
    background-color: white;}
.choice-container:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 1.4rem 0 rgba(241, 69, 175, 0.25);;
    transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
    transition: transform 150ms;}
.choice-prefix{
    padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
    background-color:#f76b8a;
    color: white;}
.choice-text{
    padding: 1.5rem;
    width: 100% ;}
.correct{
    background-color: #28a745;
}
.incorrect{
    background-color: #dc3545;
}
/* hud */
#hud {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.hud-prefix{
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 2rem;}
#questionCounter{
    display: flex;
    left: 3%;
    top:45%;}
#score{
    display: flex;
    top:45%;
    left: 91%;
}
#hud-item{
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
#progressBar{
    width:20rem;
    height: 4rem;
    border: 0.3rem solid #f76b8a ;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;

}

#progressBarfull{
    height: 3.6rem;
    width: 0%;
    background-color:#f76b8a ;
}

//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset+"UTS-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge" />
        <title> Quick Quiz </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class"container">
            <div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column">
              <h1>Quick Quiz</h1>
              <a class="btn" href="/game.html">play</a>
              <a class="btn" href="/highscors.html">High Scores</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

//app.css
:root{
    background-color: #FFF0F5;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    color: #333;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1{
    font-size: 5.4rem;
    color: #f76b8a;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 5px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

h1>span {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

h2{
    font-size: 4.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
h3{
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/* UTILITIES */
.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 80rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:fixed;
    display: grid;
    padding: 2rem;

    
}

.container>*{
    width:100%;
}

.flex-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
  
.flex-center {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 650px;
}
  
.justify-center {
    justify-content: center;
}
  
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
  
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    width: 20rem;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.1rem solid #f76b8a;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f76b8a;
    background-color: white;

}


  
.btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 1.4rem 0 rgba(219, 135, 188, 0.5);
    transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
    transition: transform 150ms;
}
  
.btn[disabled]:hover {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: none;
}

/* FORMS */

form{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

}

input{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    width: 20rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border:none;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 1.4rem 0 rgba(220, 156, 197, 0.5);
}

input::placeholder{
    color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any JS errors reported in your console?

Comment: Nope, the console is totally fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand all of your code, but I can see a couple of issues.

In the game.js file you start by defining some DOM constants, but a couple of them happen to be undefined.

questionCounterText isn't defined because there isn't any element whose id is questionCounter or anything similar. You also have this (non-existant) element referred to in your CSS. I assume you had this HTML element but removed it at some point.

Anyway, that doesn't make your code bug. Progress text is the issue. You select it like that:

```js
const progressText = document.getElementById("ProgressText");
```

The id is capitalized. But in your HTML file, it appears like that:

```html
<p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">...</p>
```

With the first letter in lowercase. So your progressText constant is undefined, and that triggers an error when calling startGame (which by the way, I've called from the console, since there's no Start Game button).
I changed that and saw that sometimes the answer choices weren't filled with the expected text. That's because when the choices are like `<script href='xxx.js'>`, that's actually an HTML tag, and so when you use:

```js
choice.innerHTML = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
```

you're adding an script tag inside each choice. Script tags aren't dispayed by default (display: none). Poor browser will try to download the xxx.js file, with no success. You should use the innerText method to display HTML tags as text strings:

```js
choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
```

Also, your progress bar isn't working. You set its width as a weird string:

```js
progressBarfull.style.width = `Question ${(questionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100} px`;
```

Remove `Question`  from this last assignment.

You say your buttons don't work, but I can see any button.

I don't know if there's any other issue.